# JavaScript event on product configuration change

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

Is there already a *JavaScript* event for when a customer changes the configuration of a product, say changed/selected a different color? Maybe a click/change event of the switches?

**## Update 1**

We're looking for an event that we can bind to or `observe`, so we don't need to modify any existing script.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.  The main function that fires is `spConfig.reloadPrice()` for **configurable products** which is declared in `[magento-root]/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml` on `line 46`

For **simple products**, it is `opConfig` instead, which is declared in `[magento-root]/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml` on `line 185`

Both are referencing the configs sent by the blocks' `getJsonConfig` function, which can be found in `[magento-root]/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options.php` for simple products and  `[magento-root]/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php` for configurable products.

Comment: This isn't exactly what we're looking for. I have updated my question to include more details of what we want.

Comment: @user61389, did you find the solution? Could you please have a look at the similar issue  I face and see if you can share some insights at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312998/in-jquery-how-to-capture-the-data-within-spanproduct-price-span-in-the-even/313008#313008